# Powershell replacing 2nd item in cron schedule?

Tags: regex, string, powershell, text, cron

Am sure I'm way off here & there's probably an easier way to do this, but I have to change some cron text schedules & change the hour in which they run..

The cron itself is in a text file so I was thinking of using powershell to get the content, update it & save it..  but I'm not very good with regex etc with this. -I've cobbled something together from internet sources, but something is still slightly missing....

I can do all the grabbing of the file content & writing etc, it's just the slightly more advanced replacement of the 2nd variable that's an issue....

Here's my code:

```
$testText = "cron(0 20 * * ? *)"
$pattern = '(\().+?(\))'
$new1 = [regex]::Matches($testText, $pattern).Value
"new1 $new1"
$new2 = $($new1 -replace '\s+', ' ').split()
"new2 $new2"
$new3 = $new2[1]-1 #Set back an hour
#$new3 = $new2[1] -replace $new2[1],"22" #Specify Hour
"new3 $new3"
$new4 = $testText -Replace($new2,$new3)
"new4 $new4"
```

This results in this output - where annoyingly the first bit is knocked off..

```
new1 (0 20 * * ? *)
new2 (0 20 * * ? *)
new3 19
new4 cron(19* * ? *)
```

I've split this using spaces as the 1st item after the parenthesis can be 1 or 2 digits & after the 2nd set of chars(the hour) these can also be different.. i.e. cron(30 06 ? * MON-FRI *)

Any help would be appreciated... - it's been a long day & my brain is very tired!!

Comment: Using Powershell for a very Unix-y task like this seems weird. `awk '{ $2 -= 1 }1'` would do what you seem to want...?

Comment: @tripleee - yes indeed, but Powershell is my only choice for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$testText = "cron(0 20 * * ? *)"

$cron = $testText.split(' ').split('(').split(')')

'cron(' + 
$cron[1] + ' ' + 
(([datetime]::Today).AddHours($cron[2] -1).Hour) + ' ' + 
$cron[3] + ' ' + 
$cron[4] + ' ' + 
$cron[5] + ' ' + 
$cron[6] + 
')'
```

or perhaps a little easier

```
$testText = "cron(0 20 * * ? *)"

$cron = $testText.split(' ').split('(').split(')')
$cron[2] = ([datetime]::Today).AddHours($cron[2]-1).Hour
'cron(' + ($cron -join ' ') + ')'
```

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, however, if you change the script above from a minus to a plus, the value is changed from 19 to 191....   

But you definitely put me in the right direction thank you!! - I just put ([int]$cron[2]+1) in & this worked..

So much simpler than I thought!!

Comment: Ok,  didn't happen when I tried it out in VS Code. But typing using [int] is always good :)

Comment: @Alex I recommend adding something like `$cron[2] = (Get-Date -Hour ([int]$cron[2])).AddHours(-1).Hour` to avoid setting the hour to -1 when it's already 0

Comment: With the help of both of you chaps I've ended up with this which I find the easiest to read:


        $cron = $sched.split(' ').split('(').split(')')
        $newTime = 'cron(' + $cron[1] + ' ' + (Get-Date -Hour ([int]$cron[2])).AddHours(-1).Hour + ' ' + $cron[3] + ' ' + $cron[4] + ' ' + $cron[5] + ' ' + $cron[6] + ')'

Thanks Again!!

Comment: Changed type in operation from [int] to [datetime]. .Net syntax takes a little bit to get used to, but is really easy (and powerfull, and fast).